# ansible-collections/azure aks Bad Request'. Details: Must define at least one system pool

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-aks

I am using ansible-collections/azure and I got this error: basically I need to define at least one system pool. But there is no example for it and it gives error for every tries which I did.

20-04-01 API is version which I used for this automation.
I follow this links. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters

https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure

If anybody can help me that would be great!

```
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_aks_payload_6b2sjfcj/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_aks_payload.zip/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/modules/azure_rm_aks.py", line 791, in create_update_aks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/containerservice/v2020_04_01/operations/_managed_clusters_operations.py", line 670, in create_or_update
    **operation_config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/containerservice/v2020_04_01/operations/_managed_clusters_operations.py", line 621, in _create_or_update_initial
    raise exp
[WARNING]: Azure API profile latest does not define an entry for ContainerServiceClient
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aad_profile": null,
            "ad_user": null,
            "addon": null,
            "adfs_authority_url": null,
            "agent_pool_profiles": [
                {
                    "count": 2,
                    "dns_prefix": null,
                    "enable_auto_scaling": null,
                    "max_count": null,
                    "min_count": null,
                    "name": "default",
                    "os_disk_size_gb": null,
                    "os_type": null,
                    "ports": null,
                    "storage_profiles": null,
                    "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
                    "vm_size": "Standard_D2_v2",
                    "vnet_subnet_id": null
                }
            ],
            "api_profile": "latest",
            "append_tags": true,
            "auth_source": null,
            "cert_validation_mode": null,
            "client_id": null,
            "cloud_environment": "AzureCloud",
            "dns_prefix": "myaks1",
            "enable_rbac": true,
            "kubernetes_version": "1.16.9",
            "linux_profile": {
                "admin_username": "azureuser",
                "ssh_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER"
            },
            "location": "uksouth",
            "name": "myaks",
            "network_profile": null,
            "node_resource_group": "nodetest",
            "password": null,
            "profile": null,
            "resource_group": "mytest",
            "secret": null,
            "service_principal": {
                "client_id": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "client_secret": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER"
            },
            "state": "present",
            "subscription_id": null,
            "tags": {
                "Environment": "Production"
            },
            "tenant": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Error creating the AKS instance: Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: Must define at least one system pool."
}
```

Comment: You deployed the example as is correct ?  The agent_pool_profile needs an new arguèrent about the agent pool type.  System or user pool type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it fixed by new pull request, I tested in my local.

https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/pull/170

Answer (score 1):

This version of the API version requires an agentPoolMode to be provided.

AgentPoolMode

AgentPoolMode represents mode of an agent pool.
Name    Type    Description
System  string
User    string

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/agentpools/get

AKS requires a minimum of one system agent node pool

Comment: yes it is correct @djsly , it is strange as I add Type object and still do I need to add 
AgentPoolMode, it gives this error:

            "agent_pool_profiles": [
                {
                    "AgentPoolMode": "System",
                    
    "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (azure.azcollection.azure_rm_aks) module: AgentPoolMode found in agent_pool_profiles. Supported parameters include: count, dns_prefix, enable_auto_scaling, max_count, min_count, name, os_disk_size_gb, os_type, ports, storage_profiles, type, vm_size, vnet_subnet_id"
}

Comment: maybe I need to change it another api version, but it is the root problem actually i already changed default api becasue I am getting error related with this bugs

https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/164
https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/163

Comment: Yeah your API version is outdated it seems.

Comment: /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py   

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py


there is two azure components in my server and I do not know which one  is considered

Comment: https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/blob/dev/plugins/modules/azure_rm_aks.py#L408 needs to be updated to support the new API you bumped it too.

Comment: I was basically looking for run playbook for create_aks  actually mean which wasn't clear to me from the documentation and so this post. However, dug into ansible source a bit and found the details also posted my findings. Thanks for looking into the question.